# Context menus and dropboxs opening in wrong screen

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, application

I'm on Linux Mint 17.2 using a FullHD laptop and a FullHD external screen.
Ocasionally, some apps, namely Firefox, will open dropdowns in the wrong screen, for instance, trying to open the menu in Firefox in the external screen shows the menu on the laptop screen.

I couldn't find anything specific to this issue and I can't point out at this point whose fault is it: Firefox or the OS. I'm not sure if this happened in other apps so far.
The issue only seems to arrise when the window is in the external screen (i.e. in the non primary screen).

Comment: What you describe occurs on multiple versions of linux (I am on CentOS), in KDE (in my case) - but has also been reported in Gnome - and often affects those using 2 secondary monitors. The only workaround I have found is to physically re-arrange the monitors, so that I can put the mis-behaving apps on the monitors in positions that "just work."

Comment: This post is already a bit old, but not solved. Right now I only get it occasionally after stopping to use a dual screen. I do, however, use multiple desktops. But it's not exclusive to multi-screen setups.