# Clicks not registered in the correct position

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm having problems pinpointing the reason for this issue.
I'm on Linux Mint with Cinnamon. Although the following happens only in Spotify, I have some other small issues that might have the same cause (e.g. [Context menus and dropboxs opening in wrong screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225582/context-menus-and-dropboxs-opening-in-wrong-screen)).

I have Spotify open in one workspace. When I change to another worspace and back, Spotify starts to register click events incorrectly. More exactly, Spotify assumes the cursor is about one cm above where it really is. If I drag the window (with Alt+drag, or by clicking slightly under the apparent location of the title bar), the window will span to it's actual position and everything will work fine once more. Changing workspaces multiple times does not worsen the problem but the issue arises consistently when changing workspace.

Edit:

- Tested with XFCE instead of cinnamon and it doesn't show the same issue.
- My laptop has a NVIDIA GM108M and an Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics Card.
- Switching to non-hardware-accelerated cinnamon also prevents the problem, while disabling all animations et al.
- Switching to noveuau drivers did not help.
- Using the Intel integrated graphics card did not help

Comment: To help pinpoint the issue, is it still a problem in a different window manager/desktop environment, like Xfce?

Comment: Installed xfce4 to test that, and it doesn't happen. Seems to be exclusive to cinnamon.

Comment: Do you happen to use the AMD Catalyst kernel module for your graphics card?

Comment: No, it's Geforce powered.

Comment: I would say this is likely to be either a problem with the graphics card driver, or Cinnamon itself. Does toggling the option for hardware mouse cursor in `nvidia-settings` change anything? (may require restarting X) Does using the `nouveau` or `vesa` driver for X instead of `nvidia` change anyhing?

Comment: Can't seem to find any option related to the mouse in `nvidia-settings`. But you might be on to something because i changed to the alternative cinnamon DE that is not hardware accelerated and the problem is gone. It is not ideal, though, because now all animations are gone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30581/discussion-between-ecc-and-alexander).